# How to get just base urls from a text file in python?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, url, text-files

I have a text file name **weburl** which have many urls I want to get only base urls using regex
 **weburls**

```
 wikimapia.org/1649944/Bahawalpur-Railway-Station
 panoramio.com/photo/84118355
 wikimapia.org/1649944/Bahawalpur-Railway-Station
 nativepakistan.com/photos-of-bahawalpur
 defence.pk/threads/pictures-of-pakistan-railways.303027
 nativepakistan.com/photos-of-bahawalpur
 panoramio.com/photo/51311162
 https://hiveminer.com/User/Pakistan Rail Buff
```

need this

```
 wikimapia.org
 panoramio.com
 wikimapia.org
 nativepakistan.com
 defence.pk
 nativepakistan.com
 panoramio.com
 https://hiveminer.com
```

Using regex how can i do it?

Comment: It seems to be subjective what you classify as a Base URL

Comment: following up on akkatracker's point, I would have thought 'defence.pk' is a baseurl but 'defence.pk/threads' is not. Are you sure the rule for what you're looking for is "base url"?

Comment: Post edited. Please check

Comment: Python has modules for parsing URLs. Why don't you try that and come back when you have some code?

Comment: Can your URL contain port specification? And if so, should it be included?

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be:

```
^(?:\w+://)?.*?(?::\d+)?(?=/|$)
```

It matches begining of line (`^`) followed by an optional protocol specification, e.g. `https://` (`(?:\w+://)?`). Then it matches any number of *anything* (`.*?`) up to an optional port specification - like `:80` (`(?::\d+)?`). Finally it checks that the match is followed by a `/` **or** an end of line `$` (the psitive look ahead `(?=/|$)`).

[Check it out here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/lTcfLW/3).

Note that if you don't want to match the port part, you could move it in to the positive look ahead. I.e. `^(?:\w+://)?.*?(?=(?::\d+)?(?:/|$))`